# How to fetch the unique result set in oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Greetings ! Can anyone please help me out for this scenario

Table: Course

```
 Course id        Course_Name    Faculty  
  C001            Engineering    Computers  
  C002            Engineering    Electronics  
  C003            Medicine       Cardiology  
  C004            Medicine       Neurology
```

My Requirement is, i need to display the the course name and Couse id with no duplication
My Expected Result should be:

C001->Engineering.

C003->Medicine.

If i Used distinct in the query am not getting the expected result, so can anyone provide the solution, I am in beginning stage in oracle 9i.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your requirement seems a bit strange. Why C001-Engineering and not C002-Engineering? Distinct means distinct rows so that will only work when you do `select distinct course_name...`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the 'lowest' (which is not a simple definition due to NLS language and sorting settings) course ID for each course name:

```
select min(course_id) as course_id, course_name
from course
group by course_name;
```

Seems like a strange requirement - the same course with two IDs doesn't sound right, even if they are in different faculties, and you're picking a random faculty essentially; but not as odd as learning on 9i. Why not learn on a current, supported version? 11gR2 is free for personal use.

Here's the [documentation for aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm), including `min`, from the current version; and the [9i version](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions2a.htm#81312) if you really want to stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregate:
As there are several mappings for a group "Course_name" its arbitrary which one you might get anyway.

```
select max('Course id'), 'Course_Name' from Course group by Course_Name
```